# How to Import DB2 full dump

Tags: db2

I have a DB2 v9.7 Dump(.gz format) which i need to import to an another DB2 database of same version.

All the tables needs to be imported in one go.

Can somebody help me in how to achieve this ?

Thankyou in adavnce.

-Nitika

Answer (score 1):

First, the DB2 backups do not have that name structure. You should have a file inside that .gz that should have a name like this

```
SAMPLE.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20131224235959.001
```

It gives the database name, the backup type; the instance that host the database; the node (when using DPF); the timestamp; and the file number.

Normally, it just change the timestamp. And in order to restore the db you should go to the directory where the file is, and then just type:

```
db2 restore db sample
```

Eventually, if it does not work, you should specify the timestamp, directory or other things:

```
db2 restore db sample from /dir taken at 20131224235959
```

If you change the instance, you should rebind some packages. Also, you should be sure that the security structure is the same in the new installation (/etc/passwd and /etc/group have the same users and groups used in DB2)

For more information, please check: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0006237.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use db2move command

```
db2move sample export


db2move sample import
```

where sample is the database name.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having `.dmp` file then you can use below commands import .dmp file.

If you have dmp file in tar or zip you need to extract this.

```
db2 –c- -svtf db2dump.dmp > log.txt
```

**Note:
It is different then: restore command as below :**

**restore db  from Path_of_the_backup_file**.

**eg:** `restore db QAST from C:\Backups\Backup_location`

**backup db  to C:\Backups\Backup_location.**

**eg**: `restore db QISST from C:\Backups\Backup_location`